# php & cookies : last $articleid visited in an array

Tags: php, cookies

I have very little experience with cookies so I don't know how to do that.

I have a t-shirt shop where each t-shirt has an `$articleID`.

Each time an user visits a t-shirt page, I would like to add the `$articleID` to a cookie. 
Then add it to an array or something so I can retrieve it later.
There shouldn't be any duplicate `$articleID` even if the visitor visited the same `$articleID` twice.

Then on the main page, I want to retrieve the list of the last 5 `$articleID` visited and display a list of the ID.

How could I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: did you consider using sessions instead ? have a look at [Cookies vs. Sessions](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/10/1/0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to store an array in your cookies you will need to serialize it so check if this code will help

```
$articles = array();

if ( isset($_COOKIE["viewed_articles"]) )
  $articles = unserialize($_COOKIE["viewed_articles"]);

if ( ! in_array($articleID, $articles)){
    $articles[] = $articleID;
}
// at the end update the cookies
setcookie("viewed_articles", serialize($articles));
```

I hope this helps and have a loop at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp)

Comment: I just noticed that the cookies will be different without the WWW in the URL. Is it possible to share the same cookie even if the user doesn't put the WWW in the browser ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$article_id = 1; // Whichever article you're currently viewing
session_start();

if ( ! isset($_SESSION['viewed_articles']))
{
    $_SESSION['viewed_articles'] = array();
}

if ( ! in_array($article_id, $_SESSION['viewed_articles']))
{
    $_SESSION['viewed_articles'][] = $article_id;
}
```

Comment: I implied from the "cookies" approach that it didn't need to be persistent storage.  And don't fundamentally alter my answers.

Comment: I would prefer with cookies since this feature will be used to display a list of the user's recently viewed t-shirts on a t-shirt shop. So i want to to be displayed even after the session expire.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Sessions? Cookies will store the values on the users computer. That data is transferred to your web server on every page load.

Sessions store data on the server side. Sessions work by storing a session ID as a cookie on the user's browser which corresponds to a session stored on the server.

If you are using PHP, you can initiate a session by using

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['key'] = 'value';
echo $_SESSION['key']; // outputs: value
?>
```